# Invensense mpu 9250: dmp

Tags: i2c, motion-detection, mpu

I'm trying to use the dmp to calculate quaternions. I can't understand how to get the dmp data output. I think that they are stored in some registers reachable using i2c but i don't know their address or in general how to get them.
Help please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a question about an embedded hardware interface. From the software point of view it is not a question about how to do something, but what to do.

Comment: Looks like asking 'how to read addresses written to by the DMP to me'? Seems a fair enough question.  Maybe one answered in here: http://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-9250-Register-Map.pdf  @Enrico do you understand in general how to use I2C to read a register on any device?